# OAuthCard & Magic Number in MS Teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I'm using OAuthCard & AAD v1 in Bot Framework v3, and have deployed my bot to MS Teams (desktop & browser). It requires me to input the magic number to finish authentication. I had thought OAuthCard would no long require magic numbers. Am I missing something, or does anyone know what channels still require magic numbers to be entered?

I'm using the sample AAD v1 Bot on [Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/AadV1Bot)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Teams, the Teams client needs to orchestrate the login process (since it's playing the role of the browser), whereas with vanilla Bot Framework (e.g. WebChat) there's a real browser to handle this.

In particular you must add token.botframework.com to your `validDomains` section. We have a writeup of how to use OAuthCard in Teams [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/authentication/auth-oauth-card).

Comment: I can't access that link

Comment: The correct link is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/authentication/auth-oauth-card)

Comment: Thanks @BillBliss-MSFT. I'm testing my bot before deploying to a team. Just to confirm then, after uploading the manifest file, Teams will use a magic number to authenticate?

Comment: @desflan - Yes, you are correct. Just to test it you can have a [personal (one-on-one) conversation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bot-conversations/bots-conv-personal) with a Microsoft Teams bot.